# Drawio mirror diagram

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Is it possible to mirror an existing diagram with connectors etc.?

By mirroring I mean to have a reversed copy of it (the nox that's in the left to go in the right and so on)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to do that with one click. There is a possibility to flip shapes when selected and reverse connectors. Not sure how your diagram looks like but I assume we don't have an easy solution if we have one at all. You can attach the file here so I could try to help.

Comment: Thank you! You can see the diagram above, I added a picture. I think you're right, I would probably have to do it manually

Comment: You're welcome. I'm afraid that this can be done only manually since your diagram is not a simple one. Regards,